# SQL Server database design for "archived but available" data

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

We have this large database (>1TB) that we intend to "shrink".  The database revolves around one main entity, let's call it "Visit".  For discussion, let's say it is a database for a medical practice.

There are a total of 30 visit "types", such as procedure, annual, follow-up, immunisation etc, each of which is a subsidary table to "Visit", e.g. "visit_immuno".

The database has accummulated some 12 years of data since 2000.  Someone has proposed that we keep about 3 years of data in the "live" version and have the rest live in an "old_data" database.  The date is ONLY stored in the "Visit" table since it is normalised.  The Visit table also contains a `ROWVERSION` column and a `BIGINT` pseudo-identity (clustered) column.  For all intents and purposes, let's say the clustering key is populated by a SEQUENCE (SQL Server 2012 Enterprise) - we shall name it `cid`.

The `visit.date` is not always in the same order as the clustering key, for example when a doctor goes on extended visitations and returns with his "briefcase" of data, it gets merged into the main table.  There are also some updates to the "visit" table that will cause the `ROWVERSION` column to be out of sync with both the `cid` and `date` columns - to put it simply, neither `ROWVERSION` nor `cid` would make suitable partition keys for this reason.

The business rule for removing data from the "live" is that the `visit.date` must be greater than 36 months **and** a child `visit_payment` record must exist.  Also, the "old_data" database does not contain any of the base tables except `visit%`.

So we end up with:

Live DB (daily use) - All tables
Old-Data DB - older data for the *`visit%`* tables

The proposal calls for a Combined DB that is a shell containing **Synonyms** to ALL the base tables in the `Live DB` (except *`visit%`*) plus **Views** that UNION ALL across the `visit%` tables in the two databases.

Assuming the same indexes are created in the `Old-Data` DB, will the queries perform well on the UNION-ALL **Views**?  What type of query patterns might trip up the execution plan for the UNION-ALL **Views**?

Comment: What's the motivation for a) archiving old data and b) keeping it accessible? Maintenance overhead? Performance problems? Does the archived data need to be seamlessly accessible to the application? With or without modification to the application?

Comment: (a) Keeping the main db small. It is replicated to 3 other envs - dev, pre-test, test. There's also the replicated mirrors and backups, all backed by expensive storage. (b) Because downstream systems currently have access to all the data, so this maintains the status quo. (c) An instance of the app could run against the "combined" DB with all the views, but I suspect it may not perform at all.

Comment: Just to clarify, the archived data is still read-write, correct? Or is it read-only?

Comment: The old data would change to read-only and 100% filled pages. The instance of the app that connects to the combined views may throw errors if someone tries something silly on old data - we don't care.

Comment: I _think_ a read-only filegroup for the historic data and  partial backup/restore would cover this, without the added muck of the shell database and synonyms. I say _think_ as I haven't meddled with the mechanics of it for some time and need to refresh my memory. No idea how it would fit with replication but I'd question why you're replicating a live database to downstream environments anyway.

Comment: @Mark The replication is not automatic per se, just the fact that occasionally but regularly, the live db is refreshed onto test/dev. Smaller live db = smaller test db.

Comment: I was thinking about filegroup backups and partitioning when I asked my question... I think that should cover the "replication" aspect if all you do are restores to the testing environment. It's not clear to me yet the performance implications with respect to partitioning the data based on your requirements, though, as it's not strictly date-based.

Comment: @Jon Let's say we lock data into 100% filled pages in read-only filegroups (I don't think partitioning works unless we add a column to give it a proper key, possibly "month archived"). Those filegroups will still need to exist on both ends (or more) of an AlwaysOn group?

Comment: It's not an issue of performance doing the archiving (at least, I don't think so), it's more about efficiently retrieving the data after it's archived. Ummm... I believe you have to have a full copy of the database at every node in an AlwaysOn group (nothing was mentioned about that in your question) for it to work, but I'm not an expert with that. If you're looking to implement some kind of solution where only the current data is highly protected with the archive data on a separate subsystem, then you'll have to architect something around that using separate databases.

Comment: Generally it's easier to keep everything in a single database if possible.

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, assume that the live database is called `LiveDb` and the achive database is called `ArchiveDb`

- Add a UNION ALL view in `LiveDb` pointing to the tables in `ArchiveDb` database via a synonym (There is no need to do a combined db with synonyms)
- "Partition" on `visit.date` and denormalise this column to `visit_payments` too if it isn't there already (this improves co-located join performance)
- Only archive the two large tables if possible (reduces chance of tripping up the optimiser). Keep the UNION ALL view and the other tables in `LiveDb` so all joins to the smaller tables are kept local
- Add a CHECK constraint on the tables in both `LiveDb` and `ArchiveDb`  that describes the range of `visit.date` contained in the table. This helps the optimiser eliminate the archive table from both seeks and scans that contain the column `visit.data`. You will have to periodically update this constraint.
- In the UNION ALL view, add a WHERE criteria which filters on `visit.data`. This is in addition to the hint you already provided in the check constraint. This maximises the chance of filters being pushed down
- If you have EE, partition the table in the archive database (But NOT in the live database). If you want to get really fancy, use filegroup level backup/restore of the archive databases to save on backup times.
- Consider putting `AchiveDb` in SIMPLE recovery mode if it isn't already. You are not likely to need transaction log backups of `ArchiveDb`
- Use INSERT... WITH (TABLOCK) SELECT ... WITH (ROWLOCK) to force minimal logging on the destination when moving data between  `LiveDb` and `ArchiveDb`

All of the above does not guarantee that the optimiser will eliminate the archive tables from seeks and scans, but it makes it more likely.

When the elimination doesn't happen. These are the effect you may see (this list may be incomplete). For seeks, you will get an additional seek on every query (this drives up IOPS). For scans, the results could be disastrous for performance as you may end up scanning both the archive and live tables. Here are the typical ways you can trip up the optimiser:

- If you join the `visit%` tables together and don't include the `visit.data` in the join criteria (this is why you want to denormalise). Because of this, you may wish to modify some of your queries
- If you get a hash join between `visit.data` and another table (for example a date dimension), you may not get the right elimination of tables
- If you try to aggregate data over the archived tables
- If you filter on anything BUT the `visit.data`, for example a seek directly on the key of the view.

For the last scenario, you can guard yourself against the worst effects by adding another check constraint on the `cid` - if this is possible. You did mention that the sequence of `cid` not "clean" with respect to the dates and progression of rows in the table. However, could you maintain a table that contains the information: "There are no `cid` above this number since this `visit.data`" or similar? This could then drive an additional constraint.

Another thing to be careful about is that parallel queries may spawn a LOT more threads once you query the partitioned view (as both "sub-tables" will be exposed to the same parallel optimisations). For that reasons, you may want to limit MAXDOP on the server or the queries that are parallel.

By the way, if you know the queries well - you may not even need the same indexes in the two databases (this assumes you are 100% sure you will get the right elimination of tables). You could even consider using column stores for `ArchiveDb`.

Answer (score -1):

The way we have done is to write the old data in batches to a newly created database and delete the old data from live db. That way both db are accessible. You can also back up the newly created database and restore it elsewhere to remove the large footprint from production servers. Hope that is an acceptable solution to your needs.

Comment: The OP needs to go farther than this to maintain application compatibility. Did you read the question?